# Is there any way to have a pointer to a parent (derived) class inside the scope of the Child?

Tags: c++, pointers

Assume the following:

```
class child : public parent
{
  public:
  fun1(parent * obj);

  //somewhere on the child class:
  fun2 ()
  {
    fun1(this::...POINTER TO THE PARENT....); //how can I do such a thing without having to create an object of parent class?
  }

};
```

I am looking for something similar to 'this' pointer that points at the address of the current class. But, is there a "this" kinda thing for referencing a parent class inside a child's class?

Comment: Your example is passing an object, not a pointer. And `this` is already implicitly convertible.

Comment: You cannot point to the parent object because there isn't a different object, the child object is also a type of parent, so that pointer would be `this`. In other words you'd just say `fun1(this)`

Comment: @StoryTeller good catch, I fixed that part. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it's still strange. Why are you passing a reference to a pointer? It's highly suspect.

Comment: A class is just a definition, it doesn't use memory in the program. `this` is a pointer to the current object, not to its class. And the current object is an object of its class but it is also an object of its parent class and of all parent classes of the parent class, recursively. That *"something"* similar to `this` you are looking for is `this` itself.

Comment: The things is this pointer needs to be modified, and passing it as a pointer won't allow any changes. That's why I am using pass by reference *&. Is this possible?

Comment: Relevant: "dynamic_cast from scratch" by Arthur O'Dwyer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzJL-8WbpuU

Comment: Post the definition of `fun1()`

Comment: Smelling an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: @MichaelWalz or it's a misunderstanding that would be solved by a book (link for OP's reference)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 2):

The parent is the base class not the derived class. Also `this` is implicitly convertible to the base class type, so you could just pass it around.

In your case:

```
class child : public parent
{
  public:
  fun1(parent * obj);

  //somewhere on the child class:
  fun2 ()
  {
    fun1(this);
  }

};
```

And finally, in the specific case you are showing, what you are trying to do doesn't make any sense. The child can access directly to any protected or public member of the base class, so you don't need to pass a pointer to the parent.

Like the following:

```
class parent
{
    /* Rest of the code here */
protected:
    int m_member;
};

class child : public parent
{
public:
    int fun1() { m_member = 1; } 
};
```

Comment: But that doesn't even compile for me! When I try to deference a protected member of the parent class through an object of the parent, it doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry, didn't try to compile it, and forget to add a return type to fun1. It should work now.

Comment: so, if inside fun1(), I allocated memory for a new parent object like this: parent * p = new parent;    and  when I try to deference p (p->m_member = 1) I get an error!